# How to find a package in NuGet?

Tags: nuget

Yes, for the simple stuff it's simple, but suppose I want to install the 2.1 version of Web API Web Host instead of the 2.2 version?  *Sometimes* you can laboriously page through hundreds of packages to find it, other times no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you've got prereleases turned on. Try changing the menu above the main listing from "Include Prereleases" to "Stable Only".

[image: screenshot]

Worse case you can always open the Package Console Manager and type:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost -Version 5.1.1
```

which will install the package using the 5.1.1 version of the package.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out.  But not sure how I'd use the command line version without knowing the version number, which you can apparently only find if you can find the package in the list.

Comment: Secondary question:  Why does "Include Prereleases" really mean "Hide stable releases"?

Comment: @HotLicks The Nuget Package Manager will only show a package once, and the latest version of a single package. When "Include Prereleases" is selected, the latest version can be a prerelease version, which is what you're running into here. To find out the available versions, I've always visited www.nuget.org directly. It is an annoying limitation of the Visual Studio Package Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PowerShell.

```
PS SQLSERVER:\> Find-PACKAGE -NAME Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost
```

Name                           Version          Source           Summary
----                           -------          ------           -------
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Web... 5.2.3            nuget.org        This package contains everything you need to host ASP.NET Web API on IIS.